# How to specify an Android SDK version in Unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I was wondering if there's any way to specify a version of the Android SDK folder in Unity3d.
Unity by default uses the newest SDK installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is specify the minVersion when building the apk for debugging or releasing. Take a look at the screenshot below to check this. I have highlightened 2 fields which will help you.

The first is the min API Level. This is the lowest OS on which the app can be installed to. This also depends on the SDK versions you have installed.

The second field I have pointed out is the type of Operating System being used. By default, theis should be set to ARM-x86 to cover all devices.

[image]

Comment: Thanks code.mi. But with this setting, you specify the minimum API. How do you specify the target API?

Comment: But you can have many sdk versions installed at the same time. Which one chooses Unity?